# edge weight of bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have difficulties in understanding certain logic. I have a bi-partite graph as below.

[image]

I wish to find the optimal match for all the vertices in left side (Viz,A1,A2,A3,A4). I got a suggestion from my friend that the summation of edge weight can be used to solve this problem. However, I am not sure, how summation of edge weight will help in this case. For example, for A1 I can say AL2 is the best match and so on. However, my friend suggested that edge weight is much more optimal solution to this problem. I am not able to understand how it can be a optimal solution. His idea was that, all of (A1,A2,A3,A4) will be connected to all of (AL1,AL2,..,AL6) and for each edge we will calculate the summation of edge weights. Can someone please help me understand what he actually means?

EDIT: I think this might not be a case of perfect matching in bipartite graphs as the nodes in left side should equal the nodes in the right side.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "optimal"?

Comment: In my example, optimal would be the edge with the maximum weight. However, my friend told that after summation of the edge weights I should use the maximum weight, which is really confusing to me.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what the problem is here. In any case, I don't think you can ask others to explain what your friend means. Why not just ask him or her?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to figure it out myself. I found he was actually referring to maximum weighted bipartite matching. I want to understand it with an example. But I am not able to find any example and that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: You'll need to define more precisely what you are looking for. For example, can each node on the left match with only one node on the right, or with multiple? Can one right node have more than one left node (like A2 and A3 both pairing with AL3, since that's the max edge from both of them), or does each left node need to pair with a single unique right node (in which case AL2, AL3, AL4, AL6 seems to be your optimal solution)...?

Comment: Each node in the left can be mapped to multiple nodes in right. And for right nodes, we can have more than one left node pairing with them. And each left node need to pair with a single unique right node is what the solution I am looking for.

Comment: @Ramesh "Each node in the left can be mapped to multiple nodes in right" conflicts with "each left node need to pair with a single unique right node". You can't do both.

Comment: I mean in the initial graph each node in the left can have multiple nodes in right. However, in the final solution, I need the left nodes to pair with a single unique right node. Sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [maximum weighted bipartite matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) can be efficiently computed in polynomial time using a max-flow algorithm, which is a special case of a linear program. There are several relationships between bipartite matchings, max-flow, and linear programs, but the [Hopkroft-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) is the most concise expression of an algorithm for solving this specific problem.

[Maximum matchings for non-bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm) can also be computed efficiently.

(All the algorithms above have weighted versions.)

**EDIT:** It was unclear from your comments whether you have a slightly different problem. If there can be a one-to-many mapping from left to right, but right nodes can only map to one left node, you effectively have a max-flow problem where the left nodes have infinite-capacity inflow and the right nodes have an outflow capacity of one. Consult [max-flow algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions) for different solution methods.